# how to detect screenshot event and stop it in cordova

Tags: cordova, screenshot

For now i am using cordova-plugin-prevent-screenshot to prevent user from taking screenshot. But it has no custom handler to show any custom notification when an user tries to take screenshot. Is there any library or code that will help me?

Answer (score 1):

Detects screenshots on Cordova for iOS. The plugin will only work on devices with iOS >= 7, however feel free to include this plugin in projects with a lower target than iOS 7. The plugin checks the iOS version before listening for events, so it won't break anything.

Installation

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-detect-screenshot
```

When a screenshot occurs, a 'screenshot' event is triggered. Simply listen for this event in your javascript.

```
document.addEventListener("screenshot", function() {
    window.alert("Screenshot");
}, false);
```

To disable the screenshots in your app, use the disable method provided by the plugin. Note that the script needs to be executed during of after the deviceready event of cordova.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    var successCallback = function(){
        console.log("The screenshots are not allowed now.");
    };

    var errorCallback = function(err){
        console.error("An error ocurred : " + err);
    };

    OurCodeWorldpreventscreenshots.disable(successCallback,errorCallback);
}, false);
```

Enable screenshots again
The plugin allow you to dinamically change the permission of the screenshots on your app. To enable the screenshots again use the enable method.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    var successCallback = function(){
        console.log("The screenshots are allowed now again.");
    };

    var errorCallback = function(err){
        console.error("An error ocurred : " + err);
    };

    OurCodeWorldpreventscreenshots.enable(successCallback,errorCallback);
}, false);
```

Comment: The `OurCodeWorldpreventscreenshots` doesn't work with iOS

Comment: @Rich  Pitifully, ourcodeworld-cordova-preventscreenshots plugin doesn't support iOS but there's another plugin that supports both Android and iOS, however you cannot change dinamically this feature. Read the documentation of the plugin here https://github.com/devgeeks/PrivacyScreenPlugin. but you can also install  the following plugins to support for both  iOS and Android : cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-privacyscreen 
# or 
phonegap local plugin add cordova-plugin-privacyscreen

Comment: Also note that you don't need to do anything but install the plugin as it will be automatically configured on the installation. The privacy will be enabled forever in your app.

Comment: I also tried this plugin, but still I was able to take screenshot even though I have added the plugin.